# get rows if count(subquery) is greater than or equal to an integer value

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8.0

I have a query that goes over each row in a table, I am going to use subquery which will return number of rows that satisfies the condition. I want it to return only rows if subquery returns more than 1 row.

My query:

```
WITH abnormal_rents as (
    SELECT r.*
      from rents r
     where r.start_time >= '2020-08-04 12:00:00'
       and (type = 'abnormal_rents'))
SELECT *
  FROM abnormal_rents t1
 where 2 <= (select count(*)
               from abnormal_rents t2
              where t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                and t2.item_id = t1.item_id 
                and t2.time between t1.time - interval 10 minute and t1.time
                and t2.rent_id != t1.rent_id);
```

So for each rows in t1, I want to check whether it has more than one row that has same user_id, item_id and time between t1.time - interval 10 mins ~ t1.time.

comparing integer value to result of count(subquery) works? If not, is there a way to do this?

I am running the query and it has been running for at least 15 mins, still not outputting result.

EDIT:
Instead of sub-querying in where statement, I've sub-queried in select statement

```
WITH abnormal_rents as (
    SELECT r.*
      from rents r
     where r.start_time >= '2020-08-04 12:00:00'
       and (type = 'abnormal_rents'))
SELECT *
     , (select count(*)
               from abnormal_rents t2
              where t2.user_id = t1.user_id
                and t2.item_id = t1.item_id 
                and t2.time between t1.time - interval 10 minute and t1.time
                and t2.rent_id != t1.rent_id) as cnt
  FROM abnormal_rents t1
HAVING cnt >= 2;
```

Comment: Do you have proper indexes defined on your table? Please add the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE abnormal_rents` to your question

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? If using MySQL 8, you can use Window functions, which will likely perform much better.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya I don't care about the performance atm so I am not sure why info about indexes are relevant

Comment: Recommendations: 1) calculate `time - interval 10 minute` in CTE and use already calculated value in main query. 2) if `rent_id` is unique then remove `and t2.rent_id != t1.rent_id` condition and compare with `3`. 3) If proper indice exists then do NOT use CTE, use 2 copies of `rents` in a query with all the bunch of the conditions.